# Hover caption on image causes big white gap below image

Tags: css, image, hover, caption, removing-whitespace

I am building a website with WordPress. On my homepage I want a picture grid (10 x 3) of different products, and when you hover over each picture, a caption with the product name will pop up.

I have managed to do 3/4 of it but there's this massive white space below each row. :(

I am using the SiteOrigin editor widget to insert the image, and using HTML and CSS to code the hover effects. See below for the current coding.

HTML:

```
<div id="pic">

<img class="hover" src="http://peacefruit.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Hassaku.png" />
<p class="text">Summer Mikan</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text { 
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center; 
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }

#pic .text {
  position:relative;
  bottom:80px;
  left:0px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

#pic:hover .text {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Here's the website so you can see what I've done: http://peacefruit.net

The top row has the captions, but also, the pesky gap. The bottom three rows are examples of how I want it to look (no borders or gaps between pics). All rows and individual widgets have no padding, margins or gutters and I've already adjusted the theme padding to `0` with CSS.

I'm sure it's a simple line of code I'm missing, but it's driving me crazy! 
Please send help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your inline css for siteorigin-panels-stretch
 `overflow:hidden;
 height:164.89px;`

Hope this works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your case
the id should be unique.
So, it is better to change #pic to a class
Also, the `<p>` tag in your style contain padding-bottom and it will case the white space problem.

Change each pic to the following
HTML:

```
<div class="pic">
    <img class="hover" src="http://peacefruit.net/wp- content/uploads/2016/11/Hassaku.png">
    <div class="text">Summer Mikan</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pic{
    position: relative;
}

.pic .text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

then  it should be work.

Answer (score 1):

Stylesheets for WordPress themes can have a lot of CSS bloat, so you're on the right track creating a custom stylesheet, to tackle the styling nuances you desire.

Since this is a responsive theme, it's best to begin solving this from a mobile-first perspective.

The first thing to prune is the `bottom-margin: 30px;` for `.panel-grid-cell`, like this:

```
.home #main .panel-grid-cell {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The next thing is to correct your HTML mark-up. The value of `pic` is given to multiple `id` attributes.  [An `id` attribute is used to denote a *unique* element. The `class` attribute denotes a *non-unique* element](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/). `pic` should be assigned to `class` attributes instead, since many elements in your layout utilize this hook value. Like this:

```
<div class="pic">
```

I'm noticing that `img.hover` and `p.text` are getting wrapped in an unnecessary `<p>` tag. Make sure that this does not happen in the SiteOrigin editor.

You should then prune the `bottom-margin: 1.5em` for paragraphs inside of the `.pic` divs (note the designation of `pic` as a `class` hook `.pic`, rather than an `id` hook, which would have been `#pic`):

```
.pic p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

To get even closer, relative positioning should be used on the `.pic` div to ensure that the subsequent styling suggestion (`position: absolute;`) will take effect:

```
.pic {
  position: relative;
}
```

And then, for the text that appears when hovering an image:

```
p.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The styles above will work for mobile, but your theme is responsive, and you might need to account for some styling variations with different screen sizes.

For tablets, you'd need a media query like this:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) { 
  .some-class {
    some-property: some-value;
  }
  etc...
}
```

And finally, for desktop:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) { 
  .some-class {
    some-property: some-value;
  }
  etc....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help :) After some fiddling around with the suggestions and a software update, there is no gap now!

I thought I'd post my final code in case anyone has a similar problem and it might be of some help. (Note: there are some minor style changes which differ from the original post but have no effect on how it works).

HTML:

```html
<div class="pic">
    <img class="hover" src="http://peacefruit.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Summer-Mikan.png"/>
    <div class="text">Summer Mikan</div>
</div>
```

WIDGET CLASS:

```html
fade
```

CSS:

```css
.fade {
  -webkit-opacity: 0.6;
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.fade:hover {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.pic {
  position: relative;
}

.text { 
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center; 
  background: rgba(214, 187, 14, 0.85);
 }

.pic .text {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.pic:hover .text {
  visibility:visible;
}

.pic p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

So glad it finally works, much appreciation to everyone!